# C++ string operations giving me weird/inconsistent/wrong results

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to read a sequence which is supposed to be in the form of:
**variable** **operator** **variable** **operator** **variable**. . . and so on, where the 'variable' consists is either A , B , or C and the 'operators' are one of the four basic operators + - / * , and simply print valid if it conforms to that given form and invalid if it doesn't. Also, the conditions are that the sequence must start with a single variable and be followed (spaces are allowed in between) by an operator.

I have already made up some code where I take the string input and just have a function called 'check' to see if it returns false, making the program print 'Invalid'. Here is my main function:

```
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string m;
    cout<<"Please enter a sequence: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,m);
    bool allow = check(m);
    if(allow == true){
        cout<<"\n\nCorrect format "<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"\n\nIncorrect format \n"<<endl;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

And here is my check function:

```
bool check(string mi){
    int c=0; //using c as an index,
    mi.append("0"); //append a 0 as a signal to when the string ends
    while(c < mi.length()){
        if(mi.at(c)=='0'){}
        else if(isblank(mi.at(c))){} //So it will accept spaces between the input
        else if(mi.at(c) == 'A' ||mi.at(c) == 'B' ||mi.at(c) == 'C'){ 
            //The sequence must start with a variable...
            c +=1;    //increment to start at the next character...
            while(c < mi.length()){ //This whole loop is to check if the next 
                                //significant character is one of the operators
                if(isblank(mi.at(c))){} 
                else if(mi.at(c) !='+' ||mi.at(c) != '-' ||mi.at(c) != '/' || mi.at(c) != '*' || mi.at(c) !='0'){
                    cout<<"\n(Log)  Character at "<<c<<" was not an operator? Value: "<<mi.at(c);
                    //Why does it always come here even if the value was an operator?
                    return false;
                }
                c++;    
            }
        }
        c++;
    }
    return true; //Assume true if there are no errors...
}
```

Even if I input a correct sequence, say A+B+C , it still comes up as being invalid. I have traced the problem to the particular line of code above. Why does it do this?

Comment: You should indent your code, it's not readable like this.

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (i.e. `g++ -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Then learn how to **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`)!!

Answer (score 3):

Because your boolean logic is incorrect.

The expression:

```
mi.at(c) !='+' || mi.at(c) != '-' || mi.at(c) != '/' || mi.at(c) != '*' || mi.at(c) !='0'
```

will evaluate as true every time. For example, if mi.at(c) is a '-', then mi.at(c) != '+' evaluates to true and your into that part of the code you don't want to be in. Likewise, if i.at(c) is a '+' then mi.at(c) != '-' evaluates true and again your conditional evaluates as true again.

I believe you want to change your boolean or's (||) to boolean and's (&&).

For some unsolicited advice, personally I would suggest taking a moment to think of the problem as a state machine. This will enable you to clean up and think about what it is doing in a supportable and expandable fashion. I'm not a c++ coder, but here is how I would approach it in c as a state machine. You should be able to translate it to c++:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

main() {

    char* VARS   = "ABC";
    char* OPS   = "+-/*";
    char  c     = EOF;
    int   state = 0;

    while (((c = getchar()) != EOF) && (state < 3)) {

        // move on to next character if we have a blank or end-of-line

        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n')
            continue;

        // test to see if the character is a var or op

        int isvars = (strchr(VARS, c) != NULL);
        int isops  = (strchr(OPS,  c) != NULL);

        // based upon character type and current state, determine next state

        if (!isvars && !isops) // character is neither a valid var nor op
            state = 3;
        else if (isvars) // character is a var
            if ((state == 0) || (state == 2))
                state = 1;
            else if (state == 1)
                state = 3;
        else if (isops) // character is an op
            if ((state == 0) || (state == 2))
                state = 3;
            else if (state == 1)
                state = 2;

    }

    puts((state > 1) ? "bad" : "good");

}
```

And, here is the result after compiling it to 'varop':

```
$ echo "" | ./varop
good
$ echo "A" | ./varop
good
$ echo "+" | ./varop
bad
$ echo "A+" | ./varop
bad
$ echo "AA" | ./varop
bad
$ echo "A+" | ./varop
bad
$ echo "A+A" | ./varop
good
$ echo "A++" | ./varop
bad
$ echo "A + B" | ./varop
good
$ echo "   A + B" | ./varop
good
$ echo "D" | ./varop
bad
$ echo "%" | ./varop
bad
```

Comment: State '0' == initial state, no VARS or OPS encountered; State '1' == Just read a VAR, waiting for an OPS or EOF; State '2' == Just read an OPS, waiting for a VAR; State '3' == invalid string; If we hit EOF and are in states '2' or '3' then the string is bad.; This solution assumes that an empty string and a string with just a VAR are okay;

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in where your problem is, however problem is your basic logic. Because you use `||` and not `&&`, that means that your statement will **always** evaluate to true (i.e. '+' will evaluate to `false` in the first condition, but will evaluate to true when checking for not `-`). What you need to do is replace the `||` operators in the culprit line with `&&` and your check function should behave as expected.


Also, as a style note, on line 8 of your check function, instead of `c += 1`, you should use `c++` for the sake of consistancy.

Answer (score 2):

Try this out, it compiles and gives the desired output. However it still not enforcing that an operator should be followed by a character for example. But i guess you can figure that out.

```
using namespace std;
```

To help, i made an array of possible operators along with a function that checks if a character is an operator or not.

```
unsigned char operators[] = { '+','-','/','*' };


bool isOperator(const unsigned char &m) {
    for (int n = 0; n < 4; n++) if (m == operators[n]) return true;
    return false;
}
```

In your check there is only one loop needed and a for loop is much more conveniant. Notice the logic, i continue when the character is a A or B or C or when it is blank.

```
bool check(string mi){
    for (int c = 0; c < mi.size(); c++) {
        cout << mi.at(c);
        if (isblank(mi.at(c))) continue;
        if (mi.at(c) == 'A' || mi.at(c) == 'B' || mi.at(c) == 'C') continue;
        if (!isOperator(mi.at(c))) {
            cout<<"\n(Log)  Character at " << c <<" was not an operator? Value: "<<mi.at(c);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true; //Assume true if there are no errors...
}

int main() {
    string m;
    cout<<"Please enter a sequence: "<<endl;
    getline(cin,m);

    cout << "\n\n" << string(check(m) ? "Correct":"Incorrect") << " format." << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Please enter a sequence:
A+B+C
A+B+C

Correct format.
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and using [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to get the separate components into a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of characters. Then it's simple to iterate over the vector to check for only the valid components.

To help with getting the components into the vector with `std::copy`, I suggest you read about [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) and [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter).

Comment: horrible suggestion. The code will still be broken, but slower and more lines to no help. The chars of a `std::string` can be iterated without coping to a `std::vector`

Comment: @vidstige Broken how? And even if there's more lines, there will be fewer expressions and statements, which can be better optimized by the compiler. And as for putting in a vector? To be prepared for when (if?) the system should be expanded to handle multi-character variables and operators. Designing (and coding) for the future is always a good idea. And generally, using what's in the C++ standard library is *always* a good idea, no need to reinvent the wheel etc.

Comment: it will be obviously be more code because you're copying the string. When not copying the string there will be less code. Think about declaring the vector variable, the actual copying, etc. I'm not saying not using the standard library, but you should first learn to use it correctly. Coding for the future is the #1 reason we have so crappy software today. Sure, don't burn bridges, but don't build what you need because YAGNI. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren't_gonna_need_it

Comment: the code will still be broken because you did not mention how to fix the actual problem - There is a bug in the logical expression.